# How do I post a single file to an asp.net webform from windows forms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, winforms, http

How do I post a single file to an asp.net webform from c# windows forms?

Comment: You would do this exactly the same way you would post a single file to an HTML page. There's nothing special about it being ASP.NET.

Comment: @John I think the question he is trying to ask is how do you send the file from a Windows Forms application to an ASP.NET file post handler.

Comment: @John - that wasn't really that helpful.  Luckily, @schemer was willing to assist with a useful response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using System.Net.WebClient.

See the sample on this MSDN page:
[WebClient.UploadData method (System.Net)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.uploaddata.aspx)

Comment: @schemer: thanks for the link, but in the future, please don't post .NET 1.1 links unless the question is specific to .NET 1.1.